# Overriding custom service fabric application parameters

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have now come to the point in our Service Fabric application development where we need to add a custom parameter that can be overridden at run time (as described in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration/).  We're still in the development stage...no azure production environment, yet, so this question mainly concerns running the service fabric cluster from visual studio or thru a powershell script in a VM.  I know that `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` is ran during debug and per its usage instructions in that file I can override custom parameters.  However, I can't seem to figure out where I do that in Visual Studio so that when different developers start a debug session they can set the custom parameter value to whatever makes sense in their dev environment.  Any ideas?  We have a task to research how to better handle secrets storage but we're not quite there, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple [publish profiles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-publish-app-remote-cluster/) (optionally without checking them in). One for every developer if needed.
For secrets: you can [encrypt settings](https://www.10thmagnitude.com/encrypting-settings-at-rest-in-azure-service-fabric-2/) and/or use Azure Key Vault combined with a Service Principal, similar to what is [shown here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/).

Comment: I will accept your answer as it is probably the correct thing to do.  However, for our scenario, we ended up creating a powershell script that sets up the environment prior to any debugging.  In our case, this setup only needs to happen once regardless of how many debugging sessions are started.